# How to set web app always to load desktop version?

Tags: android, ios, web, mobile

I'v developed web application that is not full responsive for mobile devices. So is there any possibility to set my app that always loads like desktop version?

Comment: Are you using web view?

Comment: When I access to my web site with mobile phone it opens like mobile app but some elements in my web app are not responsive so it doesnt work well. Only if I request desktop version in mobile app (chrome) and enter my web site than it works good. So Im asking can I fix it somehow to always load desktop version ?

Comment: Show me your code so far??? To get y a clue edit your question add some code!